# Does type-1 lambda calculus exist?

Tags: lambda-calculus, chomsky-hierarchy

I'm interested in the intersection of linguistics and computer science, I've been reading on Chomsky hierarchy, and would like to know if there exist lambda calculus types that are equivalent to the Chomsky types, especially the type-1 that's context-sensitive and has the linear-bounded non-deterministic Turing machine as an automation equivalent on the wiki.